# How can I get this idea to compile in pre 2.x boost spirit?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I have a huge grammar for xml parsing but written a while back in pre 2.x boost spirit. I would like slightly more meaningful error messages and so I though of saying:

```
#include <boost/spirit/core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/iterator/multi_pass.hpp>

const char* sourcefile;

typedef const char* base_iteratory_type
typedef boost::spirit::multi_pass<base_iterator_type> forward_iterator_type;
typedef boost::spirit::position_iterator2<forward_iterator_type> pos_iterator_t;

base_iterator_type begin(m_document.c_str());
base_iterator_type end = m_document.c_str() + m_document.size();

forward_iterator_type fwd_begin = boost::spirit::make_multi_pass(begin);
forward_iterator_type fwd_end;

pos_iterator_t pos_begin(fwd_begin, fwd_end, sourcefile);
pos_iterator_t pos_end;

try{
parse(pos_begin, pos_end, document_p);
}
catch(const boost::spirit::qi::expectation_failure<pos_iterator_t>& e)
{
//retrieve info from e.first.get_position of type file_position_base;
}
```

This, however, is not compiling with error on the line which catches the exception and complaining `expected unqualified-id before :: token`... Can i pull this off in pre 2.x spirit? the so-called "classic" interface? If so, what modifications would this need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT the expectation_failure class didn't exist in classic Spirit:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/classic/doc/error_handling.html

You will want to look at explcitily specified `parse_error`, like in the **[error_handling.cpp sample](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/classic/example/fundamental/error_handling.cpp)** from boost 1.41.

Also, in case anyone wants to spend some more time working on the above example, here's a modified version that actually compiles (modulo the broken exception handling):

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_multi_pass.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_position_iterator.hpp>

typedef const char* base_iterator_type;
typedef boost::spirit::classic::multi_pass<base_iterator_type> forward_iterator_type;
typedef boost::spirit::classic::position_iterator2<forward_iterator_type> pos_iterator_t;

int main()
{
    const char* sourcefile;


    std::string m_document;
    base_iterator_type begin(m_document.c_str());
    base_iterator_type end = m_document.c_str() + m_document.size();

    forward_iterator_type fwd_begin = boost::spirit::classic::make_multi_pass(begin);
    forward_iterator_type fwd_end;

    pos_iterator_t pos_begin(fwd_begin, fwd_end, sourcefile);
    pos_iterator_t pos_end;

    try{
        parse(pos_begin, pos_end, boost::spirit::classic::real_p);
    }
    catch(...) {}
    //catch(const boost::spirit::classic::expectation_failure<pos_iterator_t>& e)
    //{
        ////retrieve info from e.first.get_position of type file_position_base;
    //}

}
```

Comment: The error_handling.cpp linked file seems like it would just notify of an error if the grammar threw an exception...what I've been trying to achieve is an error message, somehow, which tells me a file position or so around where the parsing failed. I am not sure how to do this in classic spirit...

Oh and I also noticed an error of type "no matching function for call to boost::spirit::impl::abstract_parser<...

triggered by the call to parse..

Comment: @PalaceChan: me neither, that's what I remarked (`AFAICT the expectation_failure class didn't exist in classic`). However, you'd always be able to throw, and inspect the value of the iterator when it was thrown? Try `fwd_begin.get_position().line` upon handling the exception. (_I may have some more time to look at things tonight_). Also, perhaps you can try [`[spirit-general]`](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/spirit-general) as well